The TV series from early 90s
I only remember the opening sequence. All this time I thought that it was X-files. But as it turned it is not. There is a house in the suburbs more like a farm. It is night and it is raining heavily. The camera moves around it enters a graveyard. I think there was a face coming out of that graveyard towards the camera.

To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you watched the movie or TV show (even an approximate year or decade is helpful), and what movies or TV shows you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Could this be American Horror Story: Murder House or The Others (2000)?
